# Required but possibly undefined type

Tags: typescript

I want to create a class in TypeScript, which implements an interface in a way that it is required to have all properties of that interface, even the optional ones, but allows for the optional properties to be `undefined`.

This is `Required_ish<T>` type would be wider than `Required<T>`, but stricter than `T`, because it would require me to explicitly list all the properties. However the same values would be assignable to the parameters of `Required_ish<T>` and `T`.

I've tried this but it seems to do the same thing as `Required`:

```
type Required_ish<T> = T & { [K in keyof T]-?: T[K] | undefined }
```

---

The desired properties:

```
interface Foo {
    a: string;
    b?: number;
}

class Bar1 implements Foo               { a = ''; } // allowed
class Bar2 implements Required_ish<Foo> { a = ''; } // error
class Bar3 implements Required<Foo>     { a = ''; } // error

class Bar4 implements Foo               { a = ''; b = undefined; } // allowed
class Bar5 implements Required_ish<Foo> { a = ''; b = undefined; } // allowed
class Bar6 implements Required<Foo>     { a = ''; b = undefined; } // error

class Bar7 implements Foo               { a = ''; b = 0; } // allowed
class Bar8 implements Required_ish<Foo> { a = ''; b = 0; } // allowed
class Bar9 implements Required<Foo>     { a = ''; b = 0; } // allowed
```

Comment: This was my first hit in Google, but I thought no-one is going to have exactly the same question as me. I am using this because I need clear out a persistent object (GTM dataLayer) and this question and solution is what I need to keep the initialisation object typesafe (and remember to set any new properties that need to be cleared)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I finally found a solution. And it's more readable than I expected it to be.

```
type Required_ish<T> =
{
    [K in keyof Required<T>]: T[K]
};
```

---

Ok, but why does this work? Let's break this down.

First, I start with a homomorphic [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types):

```
type Required_ish<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] }
```

Mapped types are a feature that allows you to modify a type but maintain its  internal structure (a tuple will still be a tuple) and property modifiers (readonly, optional) unless you're explicit about it. The line I just wrote is more-or-less an identity type: for each key of `T` it returns the same type and modifiers as `T` had.

Now there are two modifiers that allow changing the requiredness of a property:

```
{ [K in keyof T]?:  T[K] } // add the optional modifier
{ [K in keyof T]-?: T[K] } // remove the optional modifier
```

It might be tempting to use `-?` here, but sadly this modifier does two things. Not only it removes the optional modifier from the property, it also removes undefined from the resulting type. This means that whenever you use `-?`, you have no way to return a type that extends undefined.

Luckily, we can get the keys not from `T`, but from `Required<T>`. As the compiler takes all the modifiers from the left-hand side (the part before `:`), the property will have the same modifiers as `Required<T>[K]`. This means that it will never be optional and the `readonly` modifier will stay unchanged. And because we haven't used the `-?` modifier, `T[K]` will stay intact and possibly undefined.

This way we effectively bypassed the side-effect of `-?` and the resulting type does exactly what I asked.

Comment: Please provide a description of why this code is a possible solution.

Comment: I revisited the code, thought about it, and found out there is a much simpler solution. Thanks!

Comment: Great solution!
Do you know, how to make this type "recursive", that the same applies to "sub-objects"?